# DatePicker date is wrongly binding to textbox-1 ? fiddle provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am dynamcically generating rows with some controls . In one of those controls i am having a textbox which is binded with datepicker .

Everything is working fine but there is a minor issue i.e when i select date from textbox-2 which is dynamically generated the selected date is apperaring in textbox-1 and textbox-2 is empty sadly .. so this goes on like if i have 10 textboxes in any textbox i select date end of the day i get the selected date in textbox-1 only ..

`You can find the excat senario here :` http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/8/

Correct me if i made any silly error

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is minor issue with the element, you created element with id so due to same id its causing problem.
please use class instead of id, it will work fine.

```
I have updated the fiddle, see here:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/10/

Comment: Hi . yes we can do that and other way around is something like just take out id and class of control we get desired output . But i need that id for saving to db . so i cant just remove that id :( only possible way is like dynamic id . any suggestions on that .. Cheers ty for reply

Comment: $element.id is undefined ?

Comment: You can use the counter in the bindingHandlers method and when creating elements you can make counter increment and then assign the new ID to the element. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/11/

Comment: ok . but i am amused why you are element.id in textbox other than date binded textbox . i need to make phonenumber textbox ( with dynamic id) where i am getting date . i dont need someothere textbox . when i tried to use in one thing i am getting same error undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at generated html when you add new fields by pressing button you will see that every text box has the same id. When you set date in calendar it searches for text box with matching id and finds first text box on your form and sets date for it. Make sure that you generate unique id for newly added controls. You can have a counter variable and increment it and append to id when you add new set of controls.

In your fiddle calendar shows for phone number field when it should probably show for date field.

Comment: yes i tought of that to make a dynamic id but i lack proper implementation . yes it should be to date textbox may be i wrongly done . whatever any ideas on how to make thigs dynamic in my senario . possible edit my fiddle . cheers

Comment: You need additional binding for unique id see that code I found as example how to do it (it isn't mine): http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JjBhY/

Comment: yes ideed i need such sort of thing but i have to do somethig to id not in databind . can i do like this `id="effective"+items.text` .